# Flot - Is it possible to add line coloring in the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I want every series to have their own individual coloring, so I can't set it through the options. I tried setting it through the data however it wouldn't work. When I checked in the debugger the line had the color property however the line being drawn still wasn't the color I wanted. I wondered if this problem was exclusive to color and I discovered that it does work for lineWidth. So I really have no idea what the problem is now.

Here's the code

```
data.push({
           data: xLine,
           editable: false,
           lines: {show: showBool, lineWidth:5, color:#000000},
           points: {show: false}
          });
```

The line width'll show up but the color won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to surround your specified color code with quotes (`" "`) for the color to work
2. The `color` option is not part of the `lines` option

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M9rwR/) example

```
data.push({
    data: xLine,
    editable: false,
    lines: {show: showBool, lineWidth:5 },
    color: "#000000",
    points: {show: false}
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm so sorry I missed your reply!